# How to use >= with uint256? / How to compare uint256

Tags: solidity, remix

Hi I have a function that returns a uint256.

```
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
    (
        /*uint80 roundID*/,
        int price,
        /*uint startedAt*/,
        /*uint timeStamp*/,
        /*uint80 answeredInRound*/
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return price;
}
```

I want to compare this amount to msg.value, but the editor says >= is not compatible with uint/int256?

```
    require(msg.value >= getLatestPrice(), "insufficient number");
```

TypeError: Operator >= not compatible with types uint256 and int256

How can I require msg.value to be greater than or equal to my uint256?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the type, given that this is a price from a pricefeed you can do that without worrying but be mindful in future contracts. The following should work:

```
require(msg.value >= uint256(getLatestPrice()), "insufficient number");
```

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you.